# Insert into with CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following value:

```
proc.procSetDebugMode(true);
etl_utils.procSetDebugMode(true);
_analysis.procRunAnalysis(360, <ID_PRCSS_EXCTN>, to_date('<BUSINESS_DATE>', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), '<CONFIG_TYPE>', <G_ROW_COUNT>);
```

which I need to insert into a specific clob column but unfortunately didn't succeed.

Any tips? The problem seems trivial but still I am unable to resolve it.

Comment: How are you trying to insert it and what happens when you try?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith 

Trying to insert with formula:
    
    insert(...) values ((...), aforementioned value, (...));

Also tried something like insert(...) values ((...), clob(aforementioned value), (...)); but didn't work as well.

Comment: Please add the code you tried and the errors you got to your question, not as comments.

Comment: So no error messages on the update statement? Did you commit? Did you try using the record editor while browsing the table in SQLDev -

Comment: @WilliamRobertson please find code below.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith the error 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis" which means that I incorrectly try to insert value into CLOB column.

Comment: what is clob? is that a function? a column in your JOB table?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. When I have apostrophe in string, I just need to add another one so everything will work out.

Comment: SQL Developer shows you via the red squiggle mark where your syntax errors are fwiw

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into JOB 
select 
1595,
clob(analysis.procSetDebugMode(true); etl_utils.procSetDebugMode(true);analysis.procRunAnalysis(360,<ID_PRCSS_EXCTN>,to_date('<BUSINESS_DATE>','YYYY-MM-DD'), '<CONFIG_TYPE>', <G_ROW_COUNT>);),
INPUT_PARAMS,
UPDATE_STAMP, 
UPDAE_USER_LOGIN, 
WARNING_TIME, 
MAX_EXCTN_TIME, 
IS_AWAITING_JOB from JOB where ID = 1585;
```